# Sending a zip file with Sinatra's attachment method not working

Tags: ruby, zip, sinatra

I'm building an app for managing subscriptions and generating mailing lists.

I'm building a feature in my app to export all the mailing lists under each subscription as multiple csv's. This generates a zip file with all the various csv's within it. Then I use the attachment method in Sinatra to send the file to the user.

However, whenever I do this, the user gets a zip file that is smaller than 1KB without any of the data - but when I look at the files on the server, the zip file is there and it has all the data in it.

Any idea why the attachment that the user downloads does not have any data?

Code I used to create and send the zip file to users:

```
require 'zip'

get '/all' do
    zip_name = 'all_mailing_lists.zip'
    File.delete(zip_name) if File.exists?(zip_name) # Delete previous version if it exists

    # Get a list of all csv files alrady created and delete them
    Dir.glob("./exports/*.csv") do |filepath|
        File.delete(filepath) if File.exists?(filepath)
    end

    subscriptions = Subscription.all # Get all subscriptions into an array

    # Iterate through all subscriptions and export to csv
    subscriptions.each do |subscription|
        export = ExportCsv.new

        mailing_list = export.export_mailing_list(subscription)

        # Create the csv
        File.open("./exports/#{subscription.name}_mailing_list.csv", 'w+') do |file|
            file << mailing_list.to_s
        end
    end

    # Zip all csv files
    Zip::File.open(zip_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
        # Find all .csv files in the exports directory
        Dir.glob("./exports/*.csv") do |filepath|
            filename = filepath.split("/").pop
            zipfile.add(filename, filepath)
        end
    end

    # Download zip file
    attachment("./all_mailing_lists.zip")
    File.read("./all_mailing_lists.zip")
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out that Sinatra has a different method called `send_file` that works better than the `attachment` method in this case.

Using `send_file` instead of `attachment` works just fine.